# Edit the value of Textarea using Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, textarea, puppeteer

I'm trying to login to Codeforces with Puppeteer. I want to edit the text within a `<textarea>` using this code
but nothing changed.

```
var url = "https://codeforces.com/enter?back=%2F"
const browser = await pupp.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: 'load',
    timeout: 0
});

//log in
await page.type('#handleOrEmail', email);
await page.type('#password', password);
await Promise.all([
    await (await page.$('#enterForm > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td > div:nth-child(1) > input')).click({ clickCount: 1 }),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
])
//log in

//problemset
await Promise.all([
    await (await page.$('#body > div.roundbox.menu-box > div.menu-list-container > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a')).click({ clickCount: 1 }),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
])
//problemset

//submit
await Promise.all([
    await (await page.$('#pageContent > div.second-level-menu > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(3) > a')).click({ clickCount: 1 }),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
])
//submit

//submiting
await page.type('#pageContent > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > input', '4A');
const txt = await page.$('#editor > textarea')
txt.type('hello')
console.log(await page.$eval('#editor > textarea', e => e.value))
Promise.all([
    await (await page.$('#pageContent > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td > div > div > input')).click({ clickCount: 1 }),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
])
```

I can't get the value of the textarea and I get this error:

> Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation

The main idea i wanted to code is

**i want to log in and submit a problem solution and check the Verdict cell in the table in this link**

https://codeforces.com/problemset/status?my=on

Comment: @ggorlen 
i know it is right but i dont know why i dont get a result or just  a square
like no result of i dont know

Comment: @ggorlen this is the entire code
i am trying to log in to codeforces 
`//submiting
await page.type('#pageContent > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > input', '4A');
        const txt = await page.$('#editor > textarea')
        txt.type('yazan abbas')
        console.log(await page.$eval('#editor > textarea', e => e.value))
        Promise.all([
            await (await page.$('#pageContent > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td > div > div > input')).click({ clickCount: 1 }),
            page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
        ])`

Comment: @ggorlen i started from [https://codeforces.com/enter?back=%2F]

went to the ** log in page > problemset page > submit page **

when i run this code .. i got empty textarea input and this error

_ Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation._

Comment: @ggorlen i edited the post and added the entire code
just add an email and password to an existing profile

Comment: @ggorlen the main idea i wanted to code is ""i want to log in and submit a problem solution and check the Verdict cell in the table in this link (https://codeforces.com/problemset/status?my=on)

Comment: You probably want innerText for textarea.

Comment: @pguardiario and how to edit the text inside the textarea  ?

Comment: the same way: `el.innerText = "xxx"`

Comment: @pguardiario 
okay i typed `const txt = await page.$('#editor > textarea');    txt.innerText = 'hello' 
   console.log(txt.innerText);` ... _it printed hello_ **ON THE OTHER HAND**  i typed `await page.$eval('#editor > textarea', e => e.innerText = "hello) console.log(await page.$eval('#editor > textarea', e => e.innerText));`  ... _it didnt printed hello_

Comment: @pguardiario beside .. i am trying to click a SUBMIT button or any URL using puppeteer `await (await page.$('selector')).click({ clickCount: 1 })` .. and sometimes it stuck and wont change the page and go to another one .. i am checking the URL by printing `page.url()` and it stay at the same page no matter what i try to click (buttons or <a> tag)

Comment: For starters, `Promise.all([await something])` is generally wrong and probably breaks your navigation -- you want to pass the promise directly to `Promise.all`, e.g. `Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), element.click()])` where both functions return promises and `element.click()` can be anything that triggers navigation. You can also pass the CSS selectors directly to `page.click`, so the nav code should be `Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), page.click("your selector here")])` throughout.

Comment: @ggorlen okay thank u .. idk why this is happening to me but i felt there is something wrong when i get to the submit page .. i tried to _click_ on any link and print the URL but it stuck at the submit page ... i tried to scape an element and print the text ..  `await page.$eval('selector' , e => e.value)`  but i got **undefined** .. idk why this page got stuck .. any ideas  please ?? ..... i tried `await page.goto` and it still stuck and wont change the URL and stay at the same page